# How to disable or remove clipboard and paste functionality in Stripe Card

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am getting crash when I am pasting the 22 numbers of text in Stripe card of monthly and yearly part.

To generate this scenario -

```
Write 1 to 22 numbers in your device (not in stripe edit text write some where else) and copy it and paste into input of expiry month and year of stripe.
```

I am using this stripe library -

```
compile com.stripe:stripe-android:'7.0.0'
```

Also I have tried this approaches but didn't work -

```
etUsername.setLongClickable(false);
android:longClickable="false"
```

---

Please any body know how to disable the paste and clipboard in Stripe please let me know

Comment: Seems like you'd want to fix the crash rather than disable copy/paste

Comment: @RyanMentley I already mentioned above I have tried all the approaches to disable the copy paste functionality but didn't working for stripe card.

Comment: stripe-android 7.0.0 is from April 2018, maybe upgrading to the latest version would also fix the crash?

Comment: @karllekko Actually If I am updating the version then it will also require minSDK version updation that will affects my other existing libraries version. That's why I want to fix this issue in my existing version = '7.0.0' . If there is any way to fix rather then updating the version code of stripe please suggest.